# Excluding values that appears in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to exclude all the attributes that in Table1 and appear in Table2 as in the given example based on the userId with condition that EventTime of item in Table1 is less than EventTime in Table2

Table1:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ UserId ║       EventTime       ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM ║
║      2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM ║
║      3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║
║      4 ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║
║      5 ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Table2:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ UserId ║       EventTime       ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ 2/15/2012 11:54:16 AM ║
║      2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:55:20 AM ║
║      3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:56:01 AM ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ UserId ║       EventTime       ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║      4 ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║
║      5 ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution:

```
    SELECT UserId
    FROM actionOff
    EXCEPT
    SELECT UserId
    FROM actionOn LEFT OUTER JOIN actionOff ON actionOn.UserId == actionOff.UserId WHERE actionOff.EventDate < actionOn.EventDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
except
select t2.*
from table2 t2;
```

Comment: Please notice that the EventTime is not the same

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to get a list of all the entries in `Table1` that have a matching entry in `Table2` with an `EventTime` *before* that in `Table1`.

Then use this to filter out the `UserId` where this occurs:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  Table1
  WHERE (UserId NOT IN  (
                        SELECT  t1.UserId
                          FROM  Table1 t1
                            INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId AND t1.EventTime < t2.EventTime
                        ));
```

Output:

```
UserId  EventTime
4       2012-02-16 23:05:03.000
5       2012-02-16 23:09:03.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `not` [EXISTS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator.

```
create table Table1 (UserId int, EventTime DateTime)
Insert into Table1 Values (1, '2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM'),
(2, '2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM'),
(3, '2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM'),
(4, '2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM'),
(5, '2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM')

Select * from Table1

create table Table2 (UserId int, EventTime DateTime)
Insert into Table2 Values (1, '2/15/2012 11:54:16 AM'),
(2, '2/16/2012 11:55:20 AM'), (3, '2/16/2012 11:56:01 AM')

Select * from Table2

--Final Query
select UserId, EventTime
from table1 t1
where not exists(Select 1 from table2 where t1.UserId = table2.UserId)
```

[Live Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d7ee749b994370ff82a9a9aa0b5a2dbb)

This looks like as shown below in the image below.

[image]

Apart from this you can also use `not in` operator to exclude the records which exist in another table.

Answer (score 0):

In this case EventTime column is not the same in Table1 and Table2 so your best option is to use `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X' X 
    FROM Table2 T2 
    WHERE T1.UserId = T2.UserId
)
```

You can get the same result using `LEFT JOIN` but `NOT EXISTS` is more performant.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.UserId = T2.UserId
WHERE T2.UserId IS NULL
```

You can get the same result using `EXCEPT` if you compare only the `UserId` column,
but then you should use another query to get all the columns

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN ( 
    SELECT UserId FROM Table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT UserId FROM Table2
) X ON T1.UserId = X.UserId
```